# Implementing simple socket communication between android device and java server using json objects

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I'm trying to build an Android application which runs a service.
The service needs to pass certain device information to a custom server and receive some from the server.
Currently I've chosen a simple socket programming and JSON objects to implement this.

Can anyone suggest a suitable library for implementing this communication?

I'm a newbie and foresee a number of complications in implementing this.

Comment: provide some codes that may show your efforts

Comment: @utility...i have only picked up how to (and implemented), a socket connection between android device and a java application implementing socket server. i have also implemented and tested code for collecting required information in android. but before get down to integrating the stuff, i'm looking for some library which would ease out this implementation....as i brought out, i'm a newbie programmer.

Comment: @anantsophia, you wouldn't want to implement things at the socket level, since maintaining it would be very difficult. you would be better off using a http library.

Comment: You should seriously consider using HTTP and a REST API on your server to serve JSON.

Comment: thanx, Kishore and EpicPandaForce. I take it that you would have some good reason to suggest HTTP.....i'll go with HTTP and use volley!! Thanx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Volley Library will make your life easy if you are looking for a library and  don't want to get into low level connection handling and they got some sample too on their [Page](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what i could pick up, Volley is an HTTP library; while i was trying to keep the server simple and connect through socket. i've also seen this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012015/android-socket-programming-continuous-server-client-communication-on-button-hi?rq=1                                           so i have doubts if it will help...please suggest!

Comment: ok, i change coarse to HTTP way!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Smak library its simple and free. Its based on SMTP. You should go through it, consider it for future enhancement

Comment: Thank you Haris, for your suggestions....as i said i'm a newbie, i would prefer to tred on more frequented track...but i appreciate your help and time permitting, will try this option as well!